# Spring boot2 actuator health is giving 404

Tags: spring-boot-actuator

Using Spring Boot 2 actuator by adding spring-boot-starter-actuator as dependency. I set server port as 9090 and base context as /api. After starting spring boot application I tried hit health url like

```
local-host:9090/application/health
local-host:9090/actuator/health
local-host:9090/api/application/health
local-host:9090/api/actuator/health
```

but none worked out

I tried to put configurations like

```
endpoints.actuator.enabled=true
endpoints.logfile.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

Can some one help me in understanding better way of using actuator.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like you've specified any prefix.
So You need to use /health directly

```
localhost:9090/health
```

I'm assuming local-host is a typo here

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried it but still same response.

Comment: Adding to above comment, In logs I am getting log statement like "Exposing 15 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'" But still I am unable to access

Comment: Hi Aditya Thank you.. Its working now with url localhost:9090/api/actuator/health

Comment: Any changes made from your end ?